# implementing simply linked list in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list

I am new to Java and trying to implement a simple linked list in Java(I know there is a special class for that) and having a problem in the toString() method for the class Tour which is not working. it's suppose to be a recursive method.

```
public class Tour {
    private Ville city;
    private Tour suivant;

    public Ville getVille() {
        return(city);
    }

    public Tour getSuivant() {
        return(suivant);
    }

    public void setVille(Ville laVille) {
        city = laVille;
    }

    public void setSuivant( Tour leSuivant) {
        suivant = leSuivant;
    }

    public String toString(){
        if(this == null) {
            return("Fin");
        } else {
            return(city.toString()+"->" + this.suivant.toString());
        }   
    }
}
```

the main method is here:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ville v1 = new Ville();
        v1.setNom("tantan");
        v1.setCoordonner(1,5);

        Ville v2 = new Ville();
        v2.setNom("Errachidia");
        v2.setCoordonner(10,6);

        Tour t1 = new Tour();
        t1.setVille(v1);
        t1.setSuivant(null);

        Tour t2 = new Tour();
        t2.setVille(v2);
        t2.setSuivant(t1);

        System.out.println(t2);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `this == null` will always be false

Comment: And *does not work* means nothing. Please give exact error.

Comment: when I print t2 It is supposed to print the whole list. this doesn't work it gives an exception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the if condition. It must terminate before you enter null, not after.

```
public String toString(){
    if(this.suivant == null)
        return(city.toString() + "Fin");
    else{
        return(city.toString()+"->" + this.suivant.toString());
    }


}
```